# How to show tooltip in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

In a particular window when I move cursor, I want to get the cursor position and want to display it in window just like tooltip. Is it possible? However I am able to get the co-ordinates by using `PointerX()` and `PointerY()` method but how should I display it like tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the OpenUserObjectWithParm() method.

Comment: ...to open which object? If I understand correctly, the OP would like to display an arbitrary text over a window like a tooltip, at a given position. He might manage to show such information with a window of kind `popup!` without any decoration?

Answer (score 0):

If your window uses datawindows (and you are using PB 11 or so) you can use the Tooltip property of the columns/controls on the datawindow object.

Comment: ...And If native tooltips are acceptable, I can share code to display some native baloon tooltips on any window control, but without forcing the coordinates, the ballon appears "somewhere over the control"

Comment: I need that baloon type only.